# ng is not recognized as an internal or external command(Angular 6)

Tags: angular6

After installing Node(latest version). I ran command `npm install @angular/cli -g`, it installed angular cli successfully. Then to verify it's installation, I tried to run `ng v`, but got the error message saying:

```
 "ng is not recognized as an internal or external command".
```

After some research, I came to know that I need to set the system variable path "C:\Users\jaiprakash.mewada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin", but it still not worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of "**C:\Users\jaiprakash.mewada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin**", I tried with path "**C:\Users\jaiprakash.mewada\AppData\Roaming\npm**" only and it worked.

We need to make sure, we are setting up the path of folder, where it can locate the "ng" files as shown below. I guess, in earlier version, ng files used to locate in bin folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5836Q.png)